# Partial links not going outbound

Tags: templating

I have links on a partial within my templates, but it seems to be trying to load a template when it should just be loading the outbound href of the `<a>` tag. I don't have a clue why this would be happening?

```
  {% if user.userWebsite %}
  <li class="list-inline-item m-1">
    <a class="btn btn-light" href="{{ user.userWebsite }}" target="_blank"><i class='bx bx-rss bx-tiny'></i></a>
  </li>
  {% endif %}
```

Will link out to `mysite.com/profile/pinterest.com/username` when really it should be going to `pinterest.com/username`

Any ideas to why?

Comment: Have you checked the links have an http or https at the start of them?

Answer (score 1):

The browser reads `user.userWebsite` as a relative URL, not an absolute one, I guess because your `user.userWebsite` field does not store the protocol, i.e.: http or https.

If you don't specify a protocol in a URL a browser *must* assume that it is a link to a resource on your own site. The solution is to either store the protocol within userWebsite (probably the best option), or prepend it in your template, e.g.:

`href="https://{{ user.userWebsite }}"`

Comment: I'd recommend prepending it in the template, and doing a find/replace to account for users who may include the protocol. For example, If a user enters "https://..." or "http://..." in your field you'll end up with repeating protocols. This will replace both protocols and output correctly: href="https://{{ user.userWebsite|replace({ 'https://': '', 'http://', '' }) }}" If the protocol is not entered, there will be no replacement, just your field content. This method ensures that you'll always get the secure protocol in your links.